# Unable to CodeFirst My DB EF 6.2 2 FK to one PK relation(MVC APP)

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to code first and add migration to this code and couldn't understand what I'm doing wrong.
keep in mind I'm trying to make an `MVC` App for placing and buying products.

which means I got two models Products and Users, I cant figure out already how I 
separate between non-registered account and registered accounts.

I thought about making a function which may return -1 if not registered and the id of the account if registered but don't know how.

this is My Code:

```
 public class Products
{

    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long OwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public Users Owner { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public Users User { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Column("Picture1", TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Picture1 { get; set; }
    [Column("Picture2", TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Picture2 { get; set; }
    [Column("Picture3", TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Picture3 { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

my Users class

```
public class Users
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and DBContext:

```
public class SiteDBContext : DbContext
{
    public SiteDBContext()
        : base("name =SiteDBContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

While I was trying to make a migration to this it cause this error:

> Introducing `FOREIGN KEY` constraint `'FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Users_UserId'` on table `'Products'` may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION` or `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, or modify other `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Thanks to everyone, if there is some understandable info here please ask and I will explain better.
thanks again!

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    OwnerId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    UserId = c.Long(nullable: false),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    ShortDescription = c.String(),
                    LongDescription = c.String(),
                    Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Price = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    Picture1 = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
                    Picture2 = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
                    Picture3 = c.Binary(storeType: "image"),
                    State = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.OwnerId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.OwnerId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);
```

this is the migration created, and still cant update the database with error that may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. anyone?

Comment: In you'r users class, where is [Key] declared

Comment: there was a key declared which I added later on. but now after the migration was added, I was't able to update-database which may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Comment: Why you using same users table primarykey as 2 columns foreign key in Products table?

Comment: Because both owner and regular user are User and got same properties,

Comment: just one is the placer of the bid and the other is the buyer

Comment: The issue is caused by SqlServer limitation. You need to turn cascade delete off for at least one of the two relationships. For more info, you can search SO for "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths" to find similar problems and solutions.